# How to add logo/decal while mix shader already full connected?

Tags: texturing

Hello my dear blender artists,
i know if we want to add some logo/decal on the model, we need to add **image texture** and connect it to the **mix shader fac** and turn the texture in **stencil** mode. but, what if the **mix shader** already full connected? how can i add the decal then?
[image]

Comment: you can add a new Mix Shader after the existing one

Comment: yeah i think about it too but, where should i connect the new mix shader then?

Comment: @ApasipepOyong: please click on "accept answer" so other users although know that the answer helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what it can give if you want to add another decal. If you want an image to be displayed just plug the color output of the *Image Texture* into the color input of the *Diffuse*. You can also use another UV map if necessary (here, see the *Input > UV Map* before the new *Image Texture*).

[image]

Comment: aw.. thank you so much bro. you da man!